# JBoss 7 in CentOS 7 always looks for jboss-as-standalone.pid in path /var/run/jboss-as

Tags: service, jboss, centos, jboss7.x, pid

I am running JBoss 7 in CentOS 7. When I run a single JBoss instance (X), where the PID path is set to JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid (in the instance X service file, in /etc/init.d/), it all works fine.

I am setting up an another instance (Y), so I cannot use the same path for the PID file, so I set the PID path for both the instances as follows in it's respective service file in /etc/init.d/.

For Instance X: JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/x-service/jboss-as-standalone.pid
For Instance Y: JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/y-service/jboss-as-standalone.pid

However, when I start the service (service x-instance start or service y-instance start), it always looks for /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid which is removed now, if not removed, both instances overwrites each other's pid file and causes conflicts.

I suspect that this might be due to some other error, hence JBoss falls back to the default directory.. but not exactly sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the script's tag: pidfile

## pidfile: /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid

modify the JBOSS_PIDFILE's value

```
if [ -z "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" ]; then
  #JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pif
  JBOSS_PIDFILE=your_specific_path
fi
```